# How to clear the command history in the console?

Tags: python

It is possible to clear the command history in the console-editor?

I tried the following code, but it crashes blender.

```
import bpy

for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen
    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'CONSOLE':
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area, 'region': region}
                    print(bpy.ops.console.clear(override, history=True))
                    break
```

Comment: This was a bug, fixed r60359. Possibly the question should be closed?