# Delete operation history from python?

Tags: python

How to delete the *History* from python?

When I click the *History* button in *Tool Shelf > Object Tools > History*, it shows list of the operations I did.
***How to clear this with python code?***

Comment: See this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3065/599

Comment: Could I ask why you want to do this? You could try saving the blend file and then reloading it.

Comment: I need some operation History's only in My History button so that I have to delete My previous Large list of History in History Button. Now I could choose very easy from my history.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is **no**.

However, you can clear the list by saving and reopening the .blend:

### From the UI:

1. Save the file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
2. Reload it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>

### With python:

1. Save the file with [`save_mainfile()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.ops.wm.html?#bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile)
2. Open the file with [`open_mainfile()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.ops.wm.html?#bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile)

For example:

```
import bpy

file="/tmp/test.blend"
bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile(filepath=file)
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=file)
```

Comment: Also, If I click 'Ctrl+Z'[Undo] then the History Cleared. Is there any way to apply this method. I had tried the Undo command, finally the History Button shows the 'Undo' in history but History Cleared...

Comment: @RasaMohamed You can run [`bpy.ops.ed.undo()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.ops.ed.html?#bpy.ops.ed.undo) and then [`bpy.ops.ed.redo()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.ops.ed.html?#bpy.ops.ed.redo) to undo and then redo the last action, which as you said clears the history. I believe the history is cleared because undo/redo works by saving copies of the file in memory and loading them when needed.